# Akka-Http update recieved json by converting to json Object

Tags: json, scala, rest, akka-http

I am trying to complete a POST  request by unmarshalling received Json,Now I want to update the json before submtting it to scala method

```
val route = (path("createDataSets") & post) {
    entity(as[DataSetEntity]) { dataSetEntity: DataSetEntity =>
      complete(createDataSet(dataSetEntity).map(_.asJson))
    }

case class DataSetEntity(id:Option[Long],createDate:Option[String],name:String)
```

what I receive from JSON is **id and name** for **createDate** I need to update it with the current system date before passing it to method createDataSet.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each **case class** in scala has method **copy** and it can be called with method`s named parameter, so summarizing this:

```
val route = (path("createDataSets") & post & entity(as[DataSetEntity])) { dataSetEntity: DataSetEntity =>
  val updatedEntity = dataSetEntity.copy(createDate = Some(java.time.LocalDate.now.toString))
  complete(createDataSet(updatedEntity).map(_.asJson))
}
```